Are the allocated nodes of the login node supposed to be empty?
Because I am trying to find the reasons and solve another problem (this one with mpirun saying I have a problem with my current allocation), I tried to find the allocations of my nodes in a multinode data center
In a particular node (let's call it node 11) I got
[me@Node11 ]$scontrol show hostname
Node11

Ok... it seems Node11 is the only one allocated to Node11 (I was hoping for Node12 too though)
but then on the login node
[me@login]$control show hostname
scontrol: error: host list is empty

What? What does this mean? Is this normal?
To make things even more complicated, when I run the mpirun I commented in the beginning, in the Node11 I got an error message saying Node12 is not allocated (which it seems it is not according to the results above)
But when I try the same command (mpirun) from the login node, the error does not appear (meaning Node12 might be allocated I suppose)
Of course a different kind of error appears but that is not related to allocation but to SSH access
So what is the deal with no nodes appearing in the allocated list from the login node?
